# ASP.NET MVC open a xml and show in textarea

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, textarea

In my view, I want to open a xml file manually with a browse button and then be able to send the content of the xml to a text area with a submit button.

Here is some of my code, but I don't know how to display the xml content in my text area.

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OpenFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>    }

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.XMLContent, 15, 80, null)<p>
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OpenFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string content = string.Empty;

    // Verify that the user selected a file
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // extract file path
        var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the xml to the view somehow.
One simple option is to use the dynamic ViewBag.
So before returning the view you could add this:

```
ViewBag.content = content;
```

And then, in the view:

```
@Html.TextArea("TextAreaName", (string)ViewBag.content)
```